# Xamarin iOS Activity Indicator with Another image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Using Xamarin.iOS is it possible to change the image in an `UIActivityIndicatorView` the default image looks like this:

[image]

and I would like to use an image like this:

[image]

Comment: What activity indicator are you using (what class)? Are you using a specific nuget package? Where is your code that you are calling the indicator? 
We need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: I using default indicator in my webview.
when i start load make indicator startAnimation, in finish load indicatorStopAnimation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the animation properties on a `UIImageView` like so:

```
var images = new UIImage[40];
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    images[i] = UIImage.FromBundle($"Frame{i}");
}
ImageView.Image = images[0];
ImageView.AnimationImages = images;
ImageView.AnimationDuration = 2;
```

You can start and stop it with:

```
ImageView.StartAnimating();
ImageView.StopAnimating();
```

I made a demo of this [here](https://github.com/b099l3/StackOverflow/tree/master/CustomActivitySpinner) it looks like this:

[image]

Also will need to generate the images for the loader you want.

Comment: Thanks for help @Iain Smith

Comment: Awesome did this help fix your issue?